# Conditional Formatting - Color Scale entire row based on one column

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, vba

Suppose I want to color scale complete rows on the basis of values in a column (using excel **inbuilt color scale option in the conditional formatting menu**). How do I achieve this? Please see the following image 
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a property `Range.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color` in this [post](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/526541-visual-basic-applications-code-find-interior-color-set-conditional-formatting.html#post3244130), at Mrexcel. Using this property I was able to get color of conditionally format cell and use it for the other rows. Catch is, it works only excel 2010 onwards. I have excel 2010 so it worked for me.
Here is the exact code -

```
For i = rowStart To rowEnd
    For j = columnStart To columnEnd
        Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = Cells(i, 4).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
    Next
Next
```

Comment: I like this solution, but I guess it has the same limitation as the workaround using Word - these cells won't update dynamically when the data changes, you'll have to run the macro again to update them. Still, think it's the best we've got (if you want a true continuous colour scale)

Comment: Is there any easy solution in 2023 on Microsoft Excel for Microsoft 365?

Answer (score 7):

You don't need VBA to do this, really.

But there are two things to point out from the start:

- You won't be able to achieve your desired behavior with a single conditional formatting rule; you'll have to have a separate rule for each sales-based row color definition.
- I have found that it is much easier to achieve desired Conditional Formatting behavior in Excel using Named Ranges for the rules instead of regular formulas.

If you're still on board with me after that preamble, follow these steps to create your named range and then create your conditional formatting rules.

1. First, select the first sales cell on your sheet (uppermost row)
2. Next, give the cell a name, "SALES". Do this by pressing Ctl+F3, or select `Formulas`->`Name Manager` from the ribbon. Then select `New..`. In `Name:` enter `SALES` and in `Refers to:` enter `=$XN` where X is the column of the first sales cell, and N is the row number. Hit `Enter`.
3. Now select the entire cell range you wish to exhibit this behavior
4. Select `Home`->`Conditional Formatting`->`New Rule...`
5. Select `Use a Formula to Determine Which Cells to Format`and enter `=SALES=number` where number is the sales number you wish to trigger a color
6. Select `Format` and the `Fill` tab. Now you need to decide what background color you want for the sales number you chose. You can also choose other formatting options, like the font color, etc.
7. Hit OK, OK, OK. Repeat steps 3 to 6 for each different sales figure/color combination you want. If you want a color for "all sales less than X", in your rule you will enter `=SALES<number` (< is "less than"; you can also do <=, which is "less than OR equal to"). If want the rule to happen when between two numbers, you can do `=AND(SALES<=CEILING, SALES>=FLOOR)`, where ceiling and floor are the upper and lower bounds. If you want a color for "all sales greater than X", you can do `=SALES>number`.

EDIT:

To make entering your conditional formulas a bit easier, you can use the "Stop If True" feature. Go to `Home`->`Conditional Formatting`->`Manage Rules`, and in the dropdown menu choose `This Worksheet`. Now you will see a list of all the rules that apply to your sheet, and there will be a "Stop If True" checkbox to the right of each rule.

For each row color rule, put a check in the "Stop If True" checkbox. Now your formulas can be like this (just for example):

- `=Sales>25` for the green rule
- `=Sales>10` for the yellow rule
- `=Sales>0` for the Red rule

Etc, instead of like this:

- `=AND(Sales>0,Sales<=10)` for the Red rule
- `=AND(Sales>10,Sales<=25)` for the yellow rule
- `=Sales>25` for the green rule

The `Stop If True` box means that once a formatting rule has been applied to a cell, that cell will not be formatted again based on any other rules that apply to it. Note this means that the order of the rules DOES MATTER when using `Stop If True`.

Comment: I think I need to articulate my question in a better manner, I need it for "color Scale" option provided by excel. I do not want to specify color by myself. Thanks for this answer though, really insightful on how to use named ranges for conditional formatting. Going to practice it :)

Comment: Ah OK, I misunderstood. There is no option to do this with the inbuilt color scale option. You'll have to do it yourself using VBA. I of course don't know your use case, but in my opinion, you'd be much better off selecting your own colors in the manner above instead of trying to shoehorn Excel's color scale feature into working with relative references (it simply wasn't made to do that).

Comment: @GauravSinghal Probably the best way to do what you want is to write an event for your sheet that applies the color of the sales column to the rows of your range anytime the sheet is recalculated. Unfortunately I don't have time today to write this code for you, but if you know VBA at all, that should be enough to get you started. If not, time to learn.

Comment: I seem to remember reaching a dead end in this approach a while ago. It wasn't possible to pick out a cell's conditionally formatted colour with VBA, so I had to compute the rule from scratch.

Comment: @MissPalmer If that's true, what a horrible design decision on the part of MS!

Comment: indeed! here's hoping you can prove me incorrect :P

Comment: I was trying to look for an answer, and I got to know about this property "Range.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color from a post on mrexcel , and it does give me the color of conditionally formatted color. Thank you Miss Palmer and Rick Teachey for the help. Should I post my own answer ?

Comment: @GauravSinghal Absolutely. This is encouraged.

Comment: @MissPalmer You'll be interested in this. ^^

Answer (score 7):

If I understood you correctly I have been battling with the same issue. That is to format entire rows based on the values in one column, wherein the values have been formatted via Excel's Color Scales.

I found this truly ***ridiculously*** easy workaround that involves copying your color scaled cells into word, then back into excel after which you can delete the values and substitute them with whatever values you want without changing the format:

https://superuser.com/questions/973921/copy-conditional-formatting-3-color-scheme-to-another-tab/973974#973974?newreg=fc5ca6d04a5a406fa39cd4796b6a539e

All credit to user Raystafarian

Comment: Whoever voted this down, could you explain the reason. This seems to be a good non-VBA solution for the question I asked.

Comment: I'm not the down-voter, but one drawback of this method is that it does not automatically update the colors when the data changes. If changes to the spreadsheet were made so that the Profit of Product A were suddenly 12%, the line for Product A would still be orange until this workaround was performed again.

Comment: Yeah, the whole point of conditional formatting is that it updates *dynamically* with the value of a cell. This answer completely removes that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the standard conditional formatting menu, no need for VBA. You choose the option of specifying your own formula, and you can refer to a cell (lock the column with the '$') other than the one you want to highlight.

[Background Reading](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/06/10/excel-conditional-formatting-formulas/)

Comment: That I can do for "non color scales" where I provide specific format (background, border or font color) myself. Here I want to use excel inbuilt color scales.

Comment: Fair enough. You could do it manually with say 5 colour gradients (e.g. a dark red for top 20% of the population, lighter red for next 20% etc, having extracted max and min into reference cells), though if you know VBA, it's probably easier to use this at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a solution for this.  I can achieve a colour scale of 5 degrees for any range of numbers across all cells in the row with the option of only affecting cells containing data.

This is achieved by creating 5 conditional formatting rules based around the following:

```
=AND(D4<>"",$D4<>"",($D4-(MIN($D$4:$D$20)-1))/(MAX($D$4:$D$20)-(MIN($D$4:$D$20)-1))*5<=2)
```

The first argument in the `AND` function `D4<>""` is used if you only want cells containing data to be affected, remove this if you want the whole row of data colour coded.

The second argument, `$D4<>""` points to the cell in the row that contains the value to evaluate - remember the `$` to lock the column

The third argument, `$D4-(MIN($D$4:$D$20)-1))/(MAX($D$4:$D$20)-(MIN($D$4:$D$20)-1))*5<=2` evaluates the position of the value within the entire range of values and converts this into a number between 1 and 5, changing the `*5` at the end of this argument allows you to have more steps in your colour sequence.  You will need to add more conditional rules accordingly. The `<=2` indicates this is the second colour step in the sequence.

Colours 3 and 4 use the same condition but the `<=2` is changed to `<=3` and `<=4` respectively.

The first and last colour stop need a small modification if you always want the lowest number in the range to be the first colour stop and the highest number in the range to be the highest number stop.

For the minimum number in the range, adapt as follows:

```
=AND(D4<>"",$D4<>"",OR($D4=MIN($D$4:$D$20),($D4-(MIN($D$4:$D$20)-1))/(MAX($D$4:$D$20)-(MIN($D$4:$D$20)-1))*5<=1))
```

the introduction of `OR($D4=MIN($D$4:$D$20)` catches the first number in the range

Similarly

```
=AND(D4<>"",$D4<>"",OR($D4=MAX($D$4:$D$20),($D4-(MIN($D$4:$D$20)-1))/(MAX($D$4:$D$20)-(MIN($D$4:$D$20)-1))*5<=5))
```

Using `OR($D4=MAX($D$4:$D$20)` catches the maximum number in the range

Note that `Stop if True` must be ticked for all conditions and the conditions must be sorted from minimum to maximum steps in the sequence.

[Image of Conditional Formatting Rules Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOOID.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the latests versions of Excel one can do it super quickly with the following steps:

1. apply the color scale to one row,
2. select the whole row,
3. **double** click on the "Copy format" button, this turns on the repeated copy mode,
4. move down with the keyboard arrow.

Comment: Does this solution update the colours when the values in the row changes - as pointed out in previous answers?

Comment: It does, the result of this process is equivalent to independently applying the conditional formatting to each row.