# Conditional Formatting - apply colors from gradient filled column for entire table row by row

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

With Excel Conditional Formatting it's pretty easy to apply gradient fill to one column. But what I need is an entire table formatted with gradient fill based on values from a certain column.

There [already is a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731495/conditional-formatting-color-scale-entire-row-based-on-one-column) like this but about conditional formatting with only a few colors. So answers from that topic do not fit my case or seem incomplete and unclear to me.

Comment: Choose the lowest and highest values from that certain column when you setup the conditional formatting rule

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns the point is that I do not want Excel to format (set color from a gradient palette) for every cell separately. I want the same color for all cells in row depending on values in certain column. Looks like it's hard for me to explain it properly. Please check the link above; there is an illustration that can clarify my question.

Comment: You should post a data example, and the expected output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional Formatting - Color Scale entire row based on one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731495/conditional-formatting-color-scale-entire-row-based-on-one-column)